# How to implement a Kotlin property through JNI?

Tags: kotlin, properties, java-native-interface

In Kotlin, I can use the `external` keyword to delegate the implementation of a function to native code. Given that Kotlin properties are mere syntactic sugar for a pair of getter and setter functions, I assumed that it should be possible to implement a property using native code, too. However, I can't seem to figure out how.

If I prefix the `get` and `set` keywords with `external`, Kotlin tells me that it's expecting a function body:

[image]

Of course, the whole point is *not* to have a function body in Kotlin. But if I add one anyway, Kotlin (rather expectedly) tells me that external declarations cannot have a body:

[image]

Is my syntax wrong? Or is there simply no way to implement a Kotlin property using JNI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution! It *is* possible to implement properties via JNI, I was just using the wrong syntax! The correct syntax is:

```
class Test {
    var value: Int
        external get // No parentheses or parameter list!
        external set
}
```

This syntax doesn't seem to be documented yet.

**Edit:** I created a PR for the Kotlin documentation, which has been merged. So now [this feature is officially documented](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#using-jni-with-kotlin).

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess. I haven't tried it. The documentation doesn't mention `external` for properties, so you might have to pass through like this.

```
class Foo {
    var bar: Int
        get() = getBarNative()
        set(value) = setBarNative(value)
    private external fun getBarNative(): Int
    private external fun setBarNative(value: Int)
}
```

Comment: That's a workaround in case it isn't possible to directly implement the property via JNI. I'm still hoping it's possible.